# How to sum calculated in qweb report odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

How to calculated many record in report **qweb** use **odoo**. I tried to create method in report **py** to calculate

```
@api.one
@api.depends("total_do")
def _get_total(self):
    batch_ids = self.batch_ids
    total_do = self.total_do
    for in item batch_ids:
        total_do += item.qty_received
        print total_do
```

and i show in qweb like this :

```
<div class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid  #568eff;border-left:0px;"> 
    <span t-esc="o.total_do" />
</div>
```

When I print report, I want to show total from many row . and in my case just show 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set your total method in localcontext of that model (report_sxw.rml_parse)

```
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context): 
    super(class_name, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update({
           'time': time,
           '_get_total': self._get_total,
    })
```

You just need to update that portion from where you calling that total method.

```
<div class="col-xs-1" style="text-align:center;border: 1px solid  #568eff;border-left:0px;"> 
    <span t-esc="o._get_total" />
</div>
```

And your total method would be like,

```
def _get_total(self):
    batch_ids = self.batch_ids
    total_do = 0
    for in item batch_ids:
        total_do += item.qty_received
    return total_do
```

[Refer this for more help](http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you looking for this

```
<t t-esc="sum(l.amount for l in object.lines)"/>
```

and this link [QWeb loop cannot set value to vaiables outside the loop](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4461#issuecomment-72199618)